# Single command to check if file exists, and print (custom) message to stdout?

Tags: linux, files

Hope it's OK to note this, now that I've encountered it:

I'm already aware that one can test for file existence using the `test` (`[`) command:

```
$ touch exists.file
$ if [ -f exists.file ] ; then echo "yes" ; else echo "no" ; fi
yes
$ if [ -f noexists.file ] ; then echo "yes" ; else echo "no" ; fi
no
```

... but that's a bit of typing there `:)` So, I was wandering if there is a "default" single command, that will return the file existence result to `stdout`?

I can also use `test` with the exit status `$?`:

```
$ test -f exists.file ; echo $?
0
$ test -f noexists.file ; echo $?
1
```

... but this is still two commands - and the logic is also "inverse" (0 for success, and nonzero for failure).

The reason I'm asking is that I need to test for file existence in `gnuplot`, whose "*`system("command")` returns the resulting character
 stream from stdout as a string.*"; in `gnuplot` I can do directly:

```
gnuplot> if (0) { print "yes" } else { print "no" }
no
gnuplot> if (1) { print "yes" } else { print "no" }
yes
```

so I'd basically like to be able to write something like this (pseudo):

```
gnuplot> file_exists = system("check_file --stdout exists.file")
gnuplot> if (file_exists)  { print "yes" } else { print "no" }
yes
```

... unfortunately, I cannot use that directly via `test` and `$?`:

```
gnuplot> file_exists = system("test -f exists.file; echo $?")
gnuplot> if (file_exists)  { print "yes" } else { print "no" }
no
```

... I'd have to invert the logic.

So, I'd basically have to come up with sort of a custom script solution (or writing a script inline as one-liner) ... and I thought, if there is already a default command that can print 0 or 1 (or a custom message) to stdout for file existence, then I don't have to do so `:)`

(note that `ls` may be a candidate, but it's stdout output is far too verbose; and if I want to avoid that, I'd have to suppress all output and again return exist status, as in

```
$ ls exists.file 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; echo $? 
0
$ ls noexists.file 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; echo $? 
2
```

... but that's again two commands (and more typing), and "inverted" logic...)

So, is there a single default command that can do this in Linux?

Comment: how about `( [ -f py_concur.py ] && echo "file exists" )  || echo "file does not exist"`?

Answer (score 11):

Sounds like you need the exit status reversed, so you could do:

```
system("[ ! -e file ]; echo $?")
```

or:

```
system("[ -e file ]; echo $((!$?))")
```

(note that `-f` is for *if file exists **and is a regular file***. See also [this answer of mine to a related stackoverflow Q&A](//stackoverflow.com/a/40046642) for more digressions about the meaning of *exist* here).

Answer (score 11):

Use this single bash command:

```
 [ -f /home/user/file_name ]
```

The `[]` perform the test and returns 0 on success

Comment: doesn't return anything if either case -- CentOS

Comment: Works great on macOS.

Comment: You can use this to run commands conditionally with the `&&` and `||` operators: `[ -f /home/user/file_name ] || echo "File not present"` and also `[ -f /home/user/file_name ] && echo "File is present"`

Comment: @charlesreid1 's one does the job, thanks!

Comment: @charlesreid1 's one can be combined (if done in the correct order) to return the desired "yes"/"no" output: `[ -f /home/user/file_name ] && echo yes || echo no`

Answer (score 1):

What about "inverting the logic" by:

```
file_exists = 1-system("test -f exists.file; echo $?")
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the `path-to-file` do an:

```
ls path-to-file
```

If the file exists it will output the path to the file. If the file does not exist it will return nothing. If the path to file is a directory, it will return the contents of that directory.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note however that the question explicitly asks to print a _custom_ message to stdout, as this is going to be used in a `gnuplot` program. Also be careful that depending on _how_ the output is captured, the error message that `ls` prints if `path-to-file` does not exist may be captured, so it is not unconditionally true that nothing will be printed if the file does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
pwsh -c Test-Path /etc/passwd
```

...if you have PowerShell installed. It returns either the string "True", if the path exists, or "False" if it doesn't. (Do I get "sarcastically unhelpful" points for this answer?)